# jgGrid Navigator not showing icons

Tags: css, jqgrid

my jgGrid appears correctly, but the icons on the Navigator button are not appearing. There is an outline to the buttons and a tooltip when you hover over them, but no icon on the button, like a "+" or trash bin.

Also, is there a way to hide certain buttons and not others, like remove the add record butoon, but leave the delete record button.

I have followed the instructions relating to the style sheets and language files. 
Below is the code that creates a grid:

```
 // create the grid
        $(gridName).jqGrid({
            // server url and other ajax stuff 
            url: '/Admin/Blogs',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',

            height: 'auto',
            shrinkToFit: false,

            // columns
            colNames: colNames,
            colModel: columns,

            // pagination options
            toppager: false,
            pager: pagerName,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],

            // row number column
            rownumbers: true,
            rownumWidth: 40,

            // default sorting
            sortname: 'PostedOn',
            sortorder: 'desc',

            // display the no. of records message
            viewrecords: true,

            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }
            });
            $(gridName).navGrid(pagerName,
                      {
                        // settings
                        cloneToTop: true,
                        search: false
                      },
                      {}, // add options
                      {}, // edit options
                      {} // delete options
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page got jquery-ui.js and jquery.ui.theme.css with icons images in your css/images folger.

About hiding some buttons:

```
$(gridName).navGrid(pagerName,
{edit:false,search:false,del:true,add:true,view:false,refresh:false,cloneToTop: true},
// navigator options ( where true = show / false = hide )
                      {}, // add options
                      {}, // edit options
                      {} // delete options
            );
```

if you will add custom buttons, just give them id and hide :

```
$('#buttonId').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding jquery.ui.theme.css with the theme images folder everything worked.